# Java ResultSet is not being closed properly

Tags: java, plsql, try-catch, resultset, database-cursor

I have a Java application with many code snippets like the example below.  Very simple querying of an Oracle database.  Valid data is returned and parsed, then the close() functions are called.

```
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement stmt = null;

try
{
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM example");
    while (rs.next())
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    System.out.println("test1");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("error1");
}
```

I started encountering a "maximum cursors exceeded" error.  I checked my methods to determine whether ResultSets are not being closed.  The `catch` clause was never triggered, and "test1" was printed every single time.  Which means the rs.close() and stmt.close() lines are NOT being skipped.  Yet the ResultSets are not actually being closed.

I added a `finally` clause and it cleared up the issue.

```
finally
{
    if (rs != null)
    {
        try
        {
            rs.close();
            System.out.println("test2");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("error2");
        }
    }
    if (stmt != null)
    {
        try
        {
            stmt.close();
            System.out.println("test3");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("error3");
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

My question is, why do rs.close() and stmt.close() need to be called **twice**?  The calls in the `try` clause appear to do nothing.  Yet I call them again in the `finally` clause, and they are successful.  How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use [try-with-resources](https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources) (Java 7+):

```
try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM example")) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            // do stuff
        }
        System.out.println("test1");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("error1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## No, no need to call twice

No, there is no need in JDBC to be calling `close` twice. I suspect something else is going on.

We cannot tell for sure what is going on in your code with certainty. We cannot know if your supposedly second call actually fixed the problem. The documentation for [`Statement::close`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#close()), for example, says:

> Calling the method close on a Statement object that is already closed has no effect.

## try-with-resources

As the [Answer by Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55346941/642706) suggests, you should be using a try-with-resources.

See:

- [Java 7 tech note](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) on try-with-resources.
- [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
- [Java 9 enhancement](https://www.journaldev.com/12940/javase9-try-with-resources-improvements#java-se-9-try-with-resources-improvements) to try-with-resources, using previously-created variable within Try-With-Resource Statement.

Use try-with-resources for JDBC and also for any resource implementing [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

You can put **one or more resources in your `try( … )`**. Separate with semi-colons, the last semi-colon being optional. Java will take of tracking the resources, each being closed in the reverse order of being opened. If an exception occurs in the middle, Java knows not to try closing the null resource objects. This significantly simplifies your coding.